# How can I make my website stay when window is resized

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, resize

Right now when I resize my webpage it messes up my entire website. I have looked up solutions but they have not worked for me. I read that it might be because I have some positions set to absolute, I tried setting them to relative but that did not work. Any help is appreciated :)

Website: http://al-saba.net/

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro:400);

* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html { 
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .9;
  min-height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 2000;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Passion One';
  font-size: 200px;
  color: blue;
  letter-spacing: 1.6rem;
  top: calc(62% - 200px);
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  opacity: .8;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2001;
}

h2 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', monospace;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #6EBEDC;
  letter-spacing: .4rem ;
  top: calc(64% - 30px);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: .68 ;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2002;
}

h3 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', monospace;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #6EBEDC;
  letter-spacing: .4rem ;
  top: calc(38% - 30px);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: .68 ;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2003;
}

body {
  
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: calc(22% - 100px);
    right: calc(16% - 125px);
    letter-spacing: .6rem;
    z-index: 2002;
}

.homepage-hero-module {
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
    position: relative;
}
.no-video .video-container video,
.touch .video-container video {
    display: none;
}
.no-video .video-container .poster,
.touch .video-container .poster {
    display: block !important;
}
.video-container {
        position: relative;
        height: 106%;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: #000;
    }
.video-container .filter {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    width: 102%;
}
.video-container video {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.video-container video.fillWidth {
    width: 100%;
}

a {text-decoration: none;}

/* This class is added on scroll */
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 70px;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Navigation Settings */
nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: #5B5B5B;
  opacity: .8;
  font-family: 'open-sans-bold', AvenirNext-Medium, sans-serif;
}

nav:hover {
  opacity: .9;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 24px 24px;
}

nav li a:hover {
  color: black;
}

nav li a{
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
}

/* Screens Settings */
#screen1 {
  background: #1061E5;
  text-align: center;
}

#screen1 p {
  padding-top: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

#screen2 {
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#screen3 {
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 520px) {

  nav li {
    padding: 24px 4px;
  }

  nav li a {
    font-size: 16px;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <script src = "jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

  <script src = "script.js"></script>

  <link rel = "stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Passion+One|Source+Code+Pro" rel="stylesheet">

  <title> AL-SABA.net </title>

</head>

<body>

<header>
          <h3> Design • Code • Programs </h3>

          <h1> AL-SABA </h1>

          <h2> Personal Website </h2>
</header>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round' rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text/css'>

    <div class = "homepage-hero-module">
    <div class = "video-container">
        <div class = "filter"></div>
        <video autoplay loop class = "fillWidth">
            <source src="coding.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
            <source src="Love-Coding.webm" type="video/webm" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
        </video>
    </div>
</div>

<section id="screen1">

  <p>Scroll down</p>

  <nav class = "bar">
     <ul>
   <li class = "bar-home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class = "bar-about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class = "bar-projects"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li class = "bar-contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>

</section>

<section id="screen2"></section>
<section id="screen3"></section>



<footer>
</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Simply use more media queries and you can achieve any desired look :) For that matter, what is the *desired* output? `"messes up my entire website"` is not a clear description of a problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like everything is okay except for the "Al-Saba" `h1`. You can declare the font size using relative values that consider the viewport width.

Change your `h1` CSS. Make this: `font-size:200px;` something like `font-size:15vw`.

The "Design • Code • Programs" and "Personal Website" overlap "Al-Saba" because you have them all in the same `div`. Try this instead:

```
<header>
         <div> <h3> Design • Code • Programs </h3></div>

         <div> <h1> AL-SABA </h1></div>

         <div> <h2> Personal Website </h2></div>
</header>
```

Comment: Ok! That worked also do you know how I can fix the video background from bugging out when I resize screen?

Comment: Define "bugging out"

Comment: When you resize the page the background video isn't centered anymore.

Comment: In this line: `<video autoplay="" loop="" class="fillWidth fadeIn animated" style="width: 1343px;">` just remove the entire `style` part (all of this: `style="width: 1343px;"`). Don't replace it with anything.

Comment: I don't see this: style="width: 1343px;" anywhere? Where is that located? All  I see is this: <video autoplay loop class = "fillWidth">

Comment: You must have some javascript somewhere that is dynamically adding that. You can see it when you view the source of your webpage after it loads. You could change your CSS a bit. Change this `.video-container video.fillWidth {
    width: 100%;
}` to `.video-container video.fillWidth {
    width: 100% !important;
}`

Comment: Good! Look into media queries in the future and you can control these items a bit more based on specific screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the position.

For example try adjusting the heading element position. You can see a big different.

```
h1,h2,h3 {
position:static;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this metatag

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale=1">
```